# .net core entity framework to Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created .net core api. And I want to use entity framework. I installed Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore from nuget.I created DBFirst. 
In DbContext

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.Options.Extensions.OfType<RelationalOptionsExtension>().Any(ext => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ext.ConnectionString) || ext.Connection != null))
                optionsBuilder.UseOracle(@"User Id=test;Password=test;Server=Test;Persist Security Info=True");
            CustomizeConfiguration(ref optionsBuilder);
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
```

And In controller

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
        bmsModel model = new bmsModel();

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            var result = model.HRILETISIMEKRANIs.ToList();
            return null;

        }  
 }
```

When I debug to var result I got error like

> Feature is not supported. This error is thrown by Devart .NET Standard assemblies if license key validation fails. Possible reasons: 1. License key 
>    is not found, refer to the "Licensing .NET Standard (.NET Core) Projects" article in the product documentation. 2. Your product edition (the key was generated for) doesn't support the feature you are trying to use, refer to the editions matrix. 3. Your key is outdated for using the current product version, renew the license key in the Customer Portal.

I can build project problem is when it tries to open connection while running
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use this  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core

Comment: Apart from getting license key from Devart you can use the Entity Framework Core provider from Oracle [Oracle EF Core provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/2.18.0-beta3).
Have in mind that it is still in beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODP.NET Core has supported `.NET Core 3.0` since last year. `ODP.NET` is certified with `EF 6.4`, `.NET FW 4.8`, and support `Oracle` tool sets in `Visual Studio 2019` and `VS Code`. Oracle signed a cloud partnership with Microsoft to ensure Oracle Cloud and Oracle on-premises software integrates well with Azure. Also `DEVART` is supported too. for Devart requirements

Requirements for DEVART

- Visual Studio 2017 or higher (for Entity Framework Core 3.1 - Visual
  Studio 2019)
- If you want to use Entity Framework Core 2.2 - .NET Core
  SDK 2.2. For Entity Framework Core 3.1 - .NET Core SDK 3.0
- Latest version of NuGet Package Manager
- Latest version of Windows PowerShell